# Can I use inertia js with multi pages projects?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, inertiajs

I have a laravel project with many blades not just app blade, can I use inertiajs in this project and how?

NOTE: I'm new in Laravel development and interiajs and still discovering :)

I still didn't tried but I just read the inertia documentation and run demo app

Comment: Install dependencies first : `composer require inertiajs/inertia-laravel` , then refer to [official documentation](https://inertiajs.com/server-side-setup)